# ¿Cómo extraigo los resultados de --xpath uno a uno com xmllint?

Tags: xml, bash

Estoy tratando de extraer valores del siguiente XML:

```
..
<modo id="1">a</modo>
<modo id="2">b</modo>
<modo id="3">c</modo>
..
```

El comando que ejecuto es el siguiente:

```
xmllint --xpath '//ap/modo/@id' file.xml
```

Siendo el resultado el siguiente:

```
 id="1" id="2" id="3"
```

¿Como adapto el comando para imprimir el valor del tag y que cada valor esté en una nueva linea?

```
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si cuentas con GNU `grep` puedes usar el siguiente comando:

```
grep \
    --perl-regexp \
    --only-matching \
    --regexp='[^<>]+(?=<\/modo>)' \
    file.xml
```

**Ejemplo:**

```
$ cat file.xml
<modo id="1">a</modo>
<modo id="2">b</modo>
<modo id="3">c</modo>
```

```
$ grep --perl-regexp --only-matching --regexp='[^<>]+(?=<\/modo>)' file.xml
a
b
c
```

**Explicación:**

- `grep` usa expresiones regulares para buscar e imprimir texto que coincida con un determinado patrón.
- `--perl-regexp` interpreta la expresión regular como si tuviera sintaxis PCRE (*Perl-compatible regular expression*).
- `--only-matching` imprime solo la porción que coincida con el patrón y no la línea entera.
- `--regexp` indica el patrón que se usará.
- `[^<>]+(?=<\/modo>)` busca la cadena de texto que no sea una etiqueta HTML y que preceda a la cadena `</modo>` pero sin incluir esta última en el resultado.

Para más información, puedes leer el manual de `grep` en el [sitio web de GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual) o ejecutando `man grep` en la terminal.

**Nota:** toma en cuenta que las expresiones regulares no pueden parsear arbitrariamente lenguajes como XML. Este método funciona en este caso si la sintaxis del archivo se mantiene constante. De cumplirse esa condición, las expresiones regulares pueden ser usadas sin problemas y hasta suelen ser más rápidas que los parsers apropiados.

Comment: muchas gracias!

Comment: usar Grep, sed o similares para procesar un XML es muy, muy frágil. Tendrás que tener en cuenta mil cosas que un procesador ad hoc (tipo xmllint) ya hace. Además, esta respuesta asume un fichero XML incorrecto, sin encabezamiento ni nada (el fichero que muestras como ejemplo no es un XML válido pues no tiene una etiqueta raíz única).

Comment: @fedorqui Precisamente por ello dejé una nota al final. En cuanto al archivo del ejemplo, poco importa si es estrictamente válido porque, como bien mencioné en la nota, `grep` no entiende lenguajes como XML a nivel sintáctico por lo que no podría diferenciar un archivo válido de uno inválido. En este caso, importa más que el formato sea constante para que la expresión regular no sea tan complicada. Pese a todas sus desventajas, considero que este método es apropiado para casos sencillosa como este. Si se tratara de una tarea más compleja, usar un parser sería lo más adecuado.

Comment: Sí, efectivamente, soy el primero en haber utilizado herramientas como Grep, Awk o Sed para casos como este y estoy de acuerdo en que para casos muy particulares es de ayuda. Bueno saber que hay herramientas específicas para evitar que se convierta en un verdadero dolor de cabeza cuando la expresión se complica

Comment: +1 por la solución, es elegante. También podría simplificarse con `grep -Po '\w+(?=<\/modo>)' fichero.xml`,  aprovechando que `\w` deja fuera ">".

Comment: Buena solución +1.

Answer (score 3):

Cuenta cuántos elementos hay y luego itera uno a uno sobre ellos:

```
fichero="fichero.xml"

num_valores=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//ap/modo)' "$fichero")

for ((i=1; i<=num_valores; i++)); do
    valor=$(xmllint --xpath '(//ap/modo)['"$i"']/text()' "$fichero");
    echo "$valor"
done
```

Basado en algo parecido [de Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54558713/1983854) en [How to get XMLLINT to put --xpath results as an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54543525/1983854).

---

Ejemplo:

```
$ cat fichero.xml
<ap>
<modo id="1">a</modo>
<modo id="2">b</modo>
<modo id="3">c</modo>
</ap>

$ bash script.sh 
a
b
c
```